# Prefix all endpoints with IIS virtual directory in Swashbuckle.Core

Tags: .net, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swagger-codegen

I'm currently trying to have my endpoints prefix their base path (**/my-application/**) on Swagger.
I am running a .NET 4.7.2 application using Swashbuckle and Swashbuckle.**Core** v5.6.0.
/my-application/ is the IIS virtual directory for the application.

So lets say all my endpoints are accessible via my-website.com/my-application
I want Swagger to display /my-application/Activity for the endpoint, instead of just /Activity.

Currently the auto generated .json does set the correct values for the following properties:
"host": "my-website.com",
"basePath": "/my-application"
and the "try it out" section **does work** correctly.

Currently this is how Swagger looks:
[Undesirable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxyig.png)

This is how I want Swagger to look:
[Desirable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFU0R.png)

SwaggerConfig:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
    .EnableSwagger(c =>
    {
            c.PrettyPrint();
            c.ResolveConflictingActions(apiDescriptions => apiDescriptions.First());
    })
    .EnableSwaggerUi(c => 
    {

    });
```